# Treeview with --- select option

Tags: html, laravel, treeview

I'm building a treeview inside my Laravel application but I have a problem with the view. I'm currently getting everything under the same select box, for example:

```
demo1
demo2
demo3
```

However, I want this inside select options like:

```
demo1
--- demo2
------ demo3
```

Controller:

```
$categories = Pool::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
$allCategories = Pool::pluck('title','id')->all();
return view('admin.accept', compact(['categories','allCategories']));
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('parent_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('Pool:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('parent_id',$allCategories, old('parent_id'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Kies uw Pool']) !!}
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('parent_id') }}</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {!! Form::label('Naam:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', old('title'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Title']) !!}
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</span>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

How can I build a treeview inside my Laravel application?

Comment: How can we interpreter this *demo1 --- demo2 ------ demo3*? Can you provide an existed example?

Comment: here is the sample: [link]https://imgur.com/XQyNwb8

Comment: How do you determine what's the main category, what's the sub, sub-sub? I see only `$allCategories` in your code.